# Search for roots in numerical solution of CoSODE

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

Is there a way to find out the roots of the system numerically?

For the toy model described by the coupled second order differential equation (CoSODE),

$a\ddot{x}-cy=0$

$a\ddot{y}-cx=0$

the solution is,

$ x(t)=Ae^{iwt}$

$ y(t)=Be^{iwt}.$

Substituting the solutions back into the differential equations and simplifying yields

$-aw^2=c\frac{B}{A}$

$-aw^2=c\frac{A}{B}$

and multiplying the above together yields,

$F(w) = (aw^2)^2-c^2.$

Solving for roots when F(w) = 0 yields,

$ w=\pm\sqrt{(c/a)}$

The above is a simple problem enough to allow us to solve it analytically and use it to find (possible complex) roots of F(w).   Can the above be done to find roots of F(w) numerically with one undefined parameter say $a$ is unknown?   The reason I am asking is that some CoSODE are more complicated and nonlinear hence finding the solution of the differential equation analytically/symbolically is impossible. Furthermore, the determinant cannot be employed in complicated case because of nonlinear terms.   (Note that I do not have access to the latest version of mathematica (12)).

Below is my attempt, although this approach might not be correct.

```
  a = 1.0;
  c = 0.5;
  solution = NDSolve[{a*x’’[t]-c*y[t]==0,a*y[t]-c*x[t]==0,x[0]==1,y[0]==1, x’[0]==0,y’[0]==0},{x, y}, {t, 1, 10}];

  Plot[
  Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. solution],
  {t, 1, 10},
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Orange}, PlotRange -> All]

  Periodogram[Flatten[Table[x[t]/.solution,{t,0,10,0.1}]], PlotRange->All]
```

I though that zero crossing in  frequency domain is what I should be looking for but I believe it is not correct approach (periodogram? Fourier transform?).

Comment: You might be able to combine `WhenEvent[]` and `ParametricNDSolve[]` for this.

Comment: It's not clear, are you trying to find the period of oscillation?

Comment: I am looking for values of $w$ when (eq1*eq2) is equal to zero.  My concern is what happens when eq1 and eq2 are nonlinear and I do not know the solution for that.  Is there a numerical way to find $w$ without knowing analytical solution?  I though numerical Periodogram or Fourier transform will do   However, the solution doesn't match.

Comment: @ChrisK, one may say characteristics frequencies or eigen frequencies.